TextField 'OnValueChange' called twice without entering any input
fun TextFieldWithIconsAndErrorLabel(
    text: String,
    charLimit: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    var shouldShowMaxCharLimitError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    BasicTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { newInput ->
            if (newInput.length > charLimit) {
                shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = true
            } else {
                shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = false
                onValueChange(newInput)
            }
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
            keyboardType = keyboardType,
        ),
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = {
                keyboardController?.hide()
                onValueChange(text)
                shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = false
            }
        ),
    )
    if (shouldShowMaxCharLimitError) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            text = "Max character limit exceeded",
            style = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = PoppinsFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                color = Color.Red,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            ),
        )
    }
}

In the above code, onValueChange is called multiple times and immediately resets the boolean.
For every text input, this lambda get invoked twice.
onValueChange = { newInput ->
            if (newInput.length > charLimit) {
                shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = true
            } else {
                shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = false
                onValueChange(newInput)
            }
        }


change your onValueChange to this
onValueChange = { newInput ->
        shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = newInput.length > charLimit
        if (!shouldShowMaxCharLimitError) {
            onValueChange(newInput)
        }
    }

and remove the call to onValueChange(text) inside the onDone callback
onDone = {
    keyboardController?.hide()
    // Remove the following line
    // onValueChange(text)
    shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = false
}


I am already doing this in my code, just structured differently. That's it!

You should add
var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf(text) }

result:
var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf(text) }

BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    value = textValue,
    onValueChange = { newInput ->
        if (newInput.length > charLimit) {
            shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = true
        } else {
            shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = false
            onValueChange(newInput)
        }
        textValue = newInput
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
        keyboardType = keyboardType,
    ),
    singleLine = true,
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = {
            keyboardController?.hide()
            onValueChange(text)
            shouldShowMaxCharLimitError = false
        }
    ),
)

